# Azure Application Insight Query to get success rate

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

Have a question about how could I show success rate on Azure Dashboard.
If I have single temeletry event that indicates success or failure - it's quite simple:

```
    customEvents
    | where name == "ResponseEvent" and customDimensions.Condition == "test"
    | summarize count() by tostring(customDimensions.State) //State could be Success|Failure
    | render piechart
```

But in my case - I have 2 events: RequestEvent, SuccessResponseEvent and from those two I want to get success rate, something like: successRate = 100*successCount/requestCount.

I end up with this join:

```
    customEvents
    | where name == "RequestEvent" and customDimensions.Condition == "test"
    | summarize  requestCount = count()
    | extend joinField = "1"
    | join ( customEvents
    | where name == "SuccessResponseEvent" and customDimensions.Condition == "test"
    | summarize  successCount = count()
    | extend joinField = "1")
    on joinField
    | extend successRate = (100 * successCount / requestCount)
    //////| extend failureRate = 100 - successRate 
    | project successRate
    | render table
```

I got the value I need, but I only manage to display it as table, while I need a piechart.
I thought about adding union:

```
    let success = view () { print x=toint(80) };
    let failure = view () { print x=toint(20) };
    union withsource=TableName success, failure
    | render piechart
```

But I don't see how to do this in my request.

Or create variables using let statement and try to calculate everything and join using materialize(createRequestRecieved), but it causes quite a lot of errors and I hope some simple way exists.

Question is: maybe somebody could point me to how I could achieve this: calculate one value, maybe display it as two values (success and 100-success) and arrange them in format valid for "render piechart" operator?

And second question, not so important: could I join them by some existing field? Whey I'm trying to use joinField = tostring(customDimensions.MappingField) I'm getting an error: Ensure that expression: customDimensions.MappingField is indeed a simple name

Answer (score 1):

If you are going for a piechart, it would require a string legend field and a value on each row for that legens, so union of two results should work:

```
requests
| summarize Success = sumif(itemCount, success == true)
| project Legend = "Success", Value = Success 
| union
(requests
| summarize Failed = sumif(itemCount, success == false)
| project Legend = "Failed", Value = Failed )
| render piechart
```

Going for a barchart would allow to use both `summarize` clauses in one query without join/union and may speed up performance:

```
requests
| summarize Success = sumif(itemCount, success == true), Failed = sumif(itemCount, success == false)
| project Legend = "Status", Success, Failed 
| render barchart
```

Similarly, to calculate the rate in the same query:

```
requests
| summarize Success = sumif(itemCount, success == true), Failed = sumif(itemCount, success == false)
| extend SuccessRate = Success * 1.0 / (Success + Failed)
```

Comment: Thanks for you feedback. I need to try to adapt it, but now I can't see how your first option differs from my firs example: to check customDimensions.Condition is the same as check success == true. It is "simple" data source - 'requests', and my problem is that my data source is whole that big request, and it nol looks like a good idea to just repeat it twice to get 'union'.

Comment: Yep, in the first example, the only major difference is "union" vs. "join", join typically does cartesian product and may take up extra memory/cpu in the query, while union stitches two tables together rather nicely. Query still gets executed twice. The other examples demonstrate how to execute query only once, but they lack "piechart". I'd suggest looking up ["piechart" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/renderoperator?pivots=azuredataexplorer) to find a trick to make it work with the given result layout.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's not the best option an I'm mising something in this query language capabilities, but I could put my request in variable, apply some caching and repeat it twice, I suppose:

```
let dataSource = customEvents
| where name == "RequestEvent" and customDimensions.Condition == "test"
| summarize  requestCount = count()
| extend joinField = "1"
| join ( customEvents
| where name == "SuccessResponseEvent" and customDimensions.Condition == "test"
| summarize  successCount = count()
| extend joinField = "1")
on joinField
| extend successRate = (100 * successCount / requestCount)
| extend failureRate = 100 - successRate;
let cacheddataSource = materialize(dataSource);
cacheddataSource
| project Legend = "Success", Value = successRate
| union (
dataSource
|project Legend = "Failure", Value = failureRate 
) 
| render piechart
```

So, let and materialize more or less helps, maybe some tweaks will be necessary to display actual amount of successes and failures.